# Linux Qt QSystemTrayIcon in console application

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have a working qt application. It is not a MainWindow application and has no GUI elements at all so far. It runs on startup of the linux box (as a background service). However, it has to wait for ~40-60 seconds until it can start while the IP/DHCP sorts its self out.

So I wanted to give the user some feedback as to what is going on. I thought it might be nice to add a system tray icon to look a little bit more professional then a terminal (though I could just do that).

However, after reading the documentation on QSystemTrayIcon I am still not sure if I have to use it as part of a MainWindow style application (i.e. do I need to add main window and make the sys tray a part of that), or can I just run it within my "console" style app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i created a console application with system tray myself for win7 so i have no info about linux clients. it does not display any console, it only uses logging for output and the systemtray to display 'user readable content'.

your application need to use `QApplication` instead of `QCoreApplication` in order to draw widgets and create the `QSystemTrayIcon` to display the system tray icon. now just fill the menu as you please.

the code in `main.cpp` might look like this:

```
int main(int ac, char** av){
  QApplication a(ac, av);
  QSystemTrayIcon i;
  QMenu* m = i.contextMenu();
  m->addAction(tr("hello world!"));
  i.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

cheers

Comment: Cool, this does also work (mostly) on the linux side too.... but I can't set the icon for some reason, but can post a separate question.

Comment: you cant set it? ill need to search that question ;)

Comment: Yeah.... I put the Question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34041283/qt-qsystemtrayiconseticon-or-qicon-not-working, but after further reading around... it seems that maybe it does not work there is a bug for certain distros of linux :(