# Qt QSystemTrayIcon::setIcon or QIcon() not working

Tags: c++, linux, qt

using qt 5.5 on linux (ubuntu), I have very simple code (in main.cpp):

```
//QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
QApplication a(argc, argv);

// Test if QLabel can show the icon
QLabel *label = new QLabel();
label->setPixmap(QPixmap("icon16.png"));
label->show();

// Do the same for QSystemTray
QSystemTrayIcon i;
QIcon icon(QPixmap("icon16.png"));
i.setIcon(icon);
i.show();
//    i.showMessage("hey dude!", "this is my message");
qDebug("done\n\n");
```

So here I am trying to dislpay a system tray icon... which works, but the icon is a red circle with a cross through it (showing that no icon is available). The commented out "showMessage()" function also works fine.

I know that the icon itself can be loaded and displayed by qt because it works for the QLabel.

The problem is that the QSystemTrayIcon is not displayed.

I have been through this post [Another Persons Issue With QSystemTrayIcon](https://forum.qt.io/topic/55854/solved-qsystemtrayicon-icon-from-resource-file-isn-t-showing), but he has a different issue to me in the end.

I can't figure out what the problem is here :(

**edit**

There are these links that suggest this is broke:

- [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/56459-QSystemTrayIcon-and-linux)
- [and here](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-31762)

Comment: hi again, ensure your application is able to find the file using `QFile::exists("icon16.png")`. does the label display the image?

Comment: Yeah, the label one works perfect :)    .. I think I replied to your comment on the other post (keep it here from now)... ill post some more links, looks like it might be a broken feature or a linux distro issue...

Comment: it is possible (and i think i read about it a few month ago) that there might be problems with some window managers

Comment: @Zaiborg yeah...hmm.. well, it might be ok for me, I am using 14.04, but the target is 10.10 (really old), so it might work when I test it on that!.... if it does I'll mark this as resolved and post my findings :o

Comment: your 'broken links' tell that it works on KDE and half on Unity (so it might work on 10.10 or if you have the option to switch window manager. in the bugtracker it is fixed in version 5.5.0 (alpha)

Comment: Links broken?... work ok for me, strange :(    So I have 5.5... maybe it gets released in 5.6.

Comment: sorry, i meant your `There are these links that suggest this is broke:`

Comment: Oh I see! cool : ), I will see what happens on other distros/window managers and report back